# datetime format but i only want the month / year in the columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am performing some data cleaning to my dataframe and there are two columns labelled Tranc_Year and Tranc_Month.

The two columns are originally of int64 datatype and I want to convert them to datetime.
[image: Display of two columns]

However, after converting it to datetime with the following code:

df_train.loc[:,'Tranc_Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['Tranc_Year'], format='%Y')
df_train.loc[:,'Tranc_Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['Tranc_Month'], format='%m')

The display becomes as follows:
[image: New columns]

How do i convert to date time while maintaining the original display?

Comment: The `format` argument in `to_datetime()` is used for parsing, not for displaying. Also you cannot create an incomplete datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with columns `year, month, day` by `rename` by dictionary:

```
d = {'Tranc_Year':'year','Tranc_Month':'month'}

df1 = df_train[['Tranc_Year', 'Tranc_Month']].rename(columns=f).assign(day=1)
df_train['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1)
```